# How to fix summary field appearing on visualforce form table?

Tags: visualforce, css, web

Great day!

I need help with formatting a table in a visualforce form that's showing a table of related child records. It is comparable to the opportunity product table wherein products with prices are listed with a total. I will be posting screenshot links and I'm hoping you can help me with this.

Table:
http://screencast.com/t/Z5A4a3gEvS0

**visualforce code**

```
 #TableInfo{width: 1000px; margin: 70px 0; }
    #TableInfo table{border: 1px solid #f78f1e;border-collapse: collapse;border-spacing: 0;}
    #TableInfo table tr th{background: #f78f1e;padding: 5px;text-align: center;color: #fff;font-size: 14px;font-weight: bold;}
    #TableInfo table tr td{border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;padding: 5px;text-align: center;color: #000;font-size: 12px;font-weight: bold; height:25px;}
    #TableInfo .WidthNormal{width: 240px;}
    #TableInfo .WidthSmall{width: 200px;}
    #TableInfo .SuperBold{font-size: 17px !important;}
    #TotalWeightId{text-align: right !important;padding: 0 !important;}
    #TotalWeightId span{padding: 10px 10px;background: #f78f1e;color: #fff   !important;}

       <div id="TableInfo">            
        <apex:dataTable value="{!Bill_of_Lading__c.Skids__r}" var="boflading" id="theTable" rowClasses="odd,even" styleClass="tableClass" border="0">                                                                                      

        <apex:column width="240">                               
        <apex:facet name="header">NO OF PCS</apex:facet>
        <apex:outputText value="{!boflading.Number_of_Pieces__c}"/>                                                                              
        </apex:column>

        <apex:column width="240">
        <apex:facet name="header">DESCRIPTION</apex:facet>
        <apex:outputText value="{!boflading.Name}"/>
        </apex:column>

        <apex:column width="240">
        <apex:facet name="header">DIMENSIONS</apex:facet>
        <apex:outputText value="{!boflading.Dimension__c}"/>
        </apex:column> 

        <apex:column width="240">
        <apex:facet name="header">WEIGHT</apex:facet>
        <apex:outputText value="{!boflading.Weight__c}"/>
        </apex:column>

        <apex:column width="240">
        <apex:facet name="header">UOM</apex:facet>
        <apex:outputText value="{!boflading.UOM__c}"/>      
        </apex:column>  

        <apex:column width="240">
        <tfoot>     
        <td colspan="3" id="TotalWeightId"><span>TOTAL WEIGHT</span></td>
        <td class="SuperBold" contenteditable="true"><apex:outputText value="{!Bill_of_Lading__c.Total_Weight__c}"/></td>
        <td class="SuperBold" contenteditable="true">L</td>   
        </tfoot>
        </apex:column>  

        </apex:dataTable>        
        </div>
```

**apex extension code**

```
public void newSkid()
{
    if (updateSkids())
    {
      Skid__c skid=new Skid__c(Name=newSkidName, Dimension__c=newSkidDimension,   Number_of_Pieces__c=newSkidNumberofPieces, UOM__c=newskiduom, Weight__c=newskidweight, Bill_of_Lading__c=getBillofLading().id);
      insert skid;
     newSkidName=null;
      newSkidDimension=null;
      newSkidNumberofPieces=null;
      newskidbilloflading=null; 
      newskiduom=null;
      newskidweight=null;
      skids=null;
      }
   }
```

The table is supposed to look like this:
http://screencast.com/t/6Aw1TMb9ng

Note: Here are additional screenshots.

**What it's supposed to look like**

[image]

**What it currently looks like**

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Regards,

Pfang

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Hi Mohith, the main problem here is that the table has a summary row showing the total, the total is appearing multiple times every time a new child record is submitted. The total should appear only once at the bottom right corner. Let me see if I can post a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a footer for each record in your dataset.

Try changing your code to something like below. Notice the fact 'footer' isn't in an apex:column definition.

```
#TableInfo{width: 1000px; margin: 70px 0; }
#TableInfo table{border: 1px solid #f78f1e;border-collapse: collapse;border-spacing: 0;}
#TableInfo table tr th{background: #f78f1e;padding: 5px;text-align: center;color: #fff;font-size: 14px;font-weight: bold;}
#TableInfo table tr td{border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;padding: 5px;text-align: center;color: #000;font-size: 12px;font-weight: bold; height:25px;}
#TableInfo .WidthNormal{width: 240px;}
#TableInfo .WidthSmall{width: 200px;}
#TableInfo .SuperBold{font-size: 17px !important;}
#TotalWeightId{text-align: right !important;padding: 0 !important;}
#TotalWeightId span{padding: 10px 10px;background: #f78f1e;color: #fff   !important;}

   <div id="TableInfo">            
    <apex:dataTable value="{!Bill_of_Lading__c.Skids__r}" var="boflading" id="theTable" rowClasses="odd,even" styleClass="tableClass" border="0">                                                                                      

    <apex:column width="240">                               
    <apex:facet name="header">NO OF PCS</apex:facet>
    <apex:outputText value="{!boflading.Number_of_Pieces__c}"/>                                                                              
    </apex:column>

    <apex:column width="240">
    <apex:facet name="header">DESCRIPTION</apex:facet>
    <apex:outputText value="{!boflading.Name}"/>
    </apex:column>

    <apex:column width="240">
    <apex:facet name="header">DIMENSIONS</apex:facet>
    <apex:outputText value="{!boflading.Dimension__c}"/>
    </apex:column> 

    <apex:column width="240">
    <apex:facet name="header">WEIGHT</apex:facet>
    <apex:outputText value="{!boflading.Weight__c}"/>
    </apex:column>

    <apex:column width="240">
    <apex:facet name="header">UOM</apex:facet>
    <apex:outputText value="{!boflading.UOM__c}"/>      
    </apex:column>  

    <apex:fact name="footer">

    <td colspan="3" id="TotalWeightId"><span>TOTAL WEIGHT</span></td>
    <td class="SuperBold" contenteditable="true"><apex:outputText value="{!Bill_of_Lading__c.Total_Weight__c}"/></td>
    <td class="SuperBold" contenteditable="true">L</td>   
    </apex:facet>  

    </apex:dataTable>        
    </div>
```

Comment: Tried the footer code and I ended up with this screencast.com/t/IDYBqqefjQsP. I'm hoping that there's something we can add to the apex facet to get the total weight to reappear only once.

Comment: Can you post your html output to see what's been generated by?

Comment: Sure, here's where I'm at.
http://screencast.com/t/4v8vIyav

and this is what it needs to look like

http://screencast.com/t/N994kIFwBYBc

Thanks again Richard!

Comment: Here's another exchange we're having about it.

http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Visualforce-Development/Visualforce-child-record-table/m-p/650581/highlight/false#M66852